# Modify view model's validation when inside other view model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I need to be able to bypass/disable/change a view model's validation when inside other view model.

For example, this is my view model containing other view models:

```
public class OrderVM
{
    public SignMethod SignMethod { get; set; }
    public LoginVM LoginVM { get; set; }
    public RegisterVM RegisterVM { get; set; }
}
public class LoginVM
{
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    // More properties here...
}
public class RegisterVM
{
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    // More properties here...
}
```

And they have validation attributes (on the properties) that I would like to bypass/disable/change or add.

In this example, the view models of `LoginVM` and `RegisterVM` must contain required properties since it's a standalone view model for the login and register pages.

But, inside the `OrderVM` the required validation on `LoginVM` or `RegisterVM` should only be applied according to the `SignMethod` property, if the user has selected `SignMethod.Login` then the required validation on `LoginVM` should be applied and in `RegisterVM` should be disabled, and same for the opposite.

How can I achieve this behavior and represent it properly in the view models?

Comment: Can you share your relevant code? Or you can refer to this article first, it may be helpful to you. 
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-create-custom-attributes-csharp

Comment: @NMSL - Yes, I have updated my question with my exact problem. I didn't find anything helpful in the article. The question should be more clear now.

Comment: You could use ModelState.Remove to remove a property to being validated.You can refer to this：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092199/how-can-i-modify-my-view-model-to-check-validation-for-only-specific-properties

Comment: @NMSL - But how can I access it inside a validation attribute? and also does it remove a specific validation?